# Происхождение суффикса "-вато"

Tags: недопустимая-метка, суффиксы

Меня очень интересует происхождение суффиксов *-ват, -вато*. 
Примеры: *простоват, сложноват, многовато, маловато, мрачновата, зеленовата* и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суффикс **ОВАТ** - регулярная и продуктивная словообразовательная единица со значением неполноты качества, слабой степени качества, используется для образования прилагательных от прилагательных.

Сложный - сложн/оват/ый - сложн/оват/о, сложн/оват/а. Здесь О и А  - это **окончания** краткого прилагательного, также О может быть **суффиксом** наречия.

По структуре суффикс **ОВАТ** является сложением двух суффиксов: суффикса относительных прилагательных **ОВ** и суффикса прилагательного **АТ** со значением характерного признака (сравнить: ель - ел**ов**ый, черный - черн**ов**ой, нос - нос**ат**ый).